# Programmatically Stopping a Rails Server Gracefully on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following class that encapsulates a Rails server process:

```
require 'open3'

class RailsServer
  def self.start(port=3000)
    _, _, _, thread = Open3.popen3("rails", "server", "--port=#{port}")
    RailsServer.new(thread, port)
  end

  def initialize(thread, port)
    @thread = thread
    @port = port
  end

  def running?
    @thread.alive?
  end
end
```

So far, so good. Now though, I want to add a stop method which stops the server gracefully, giving it time to finish what it's doing, delete its pid file, etc. So I did this:

```
require "timeout"

class RailsServer
  def stop(timeout=10)
    begin
      Timeout.timeout(timeout) do
        Process.kill("TERM", @thread.pid)
        sleep 1 while running?
      end
    rescue Timeout::Error
      Process.kill(9, @thread.pid)
    end
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, `Process.kill("TERM", @thread.pid)` throws the error `Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument` on Windows. Presumably this is because because Windows doesn't support `TERM`? `Process.kill(9, @thread.pid)` works just fine, but (obviously) doesn't give the server time to finish what it was doing and delete its pid file.

So how do I make this work? Do I send a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> over `STDIN`? That doesn't really sound ideal... =/

Answer (score 0):

I would have done this : `taskkill /PID #{@thread.pid}`
Notice the backticks, it's just executing a windows command.